# Is there a repeatable place to find summon orbs (any strength)?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

The daily dungeon rewards include many types of orbs but not summon orbs. Some dungeons have them as First-time rewards or Mastery rewards, but those are obviously not repeatable.

Are there any dungeons that have summon orbs as the repeatable completion reward or as drops from enemies?  (I'm not particularly concerned about the level of the orb - I can use a bunch of any of them except the 1-star orbs right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus far in the global client, summon orbs have only become farmable during events. When there is a collection event (e.g. Aerith's event), all rarities of summon orbs are usually in the list of barterable rewards. In challenge events (e.g. Tidus), the final boss is usually the one to have a chance to drop a summon orb.

The best event thus far for farming summon orbs was the Cecil event. This event should come around again as it was reissued in the Japanese client.